# Recommendation for testing a website or web application in python

Tags: python, testing, selenium, web-testing

I am working for an eCommerce travel portal which is written in Java. So apparently i am very comfortable with Python language i am looking for a framework in python which could test the website and give us the complete information as where is the issue on which step. So i was wondering is there anything which could accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [Robot Framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/), which allows extensions in either Java or Python. We've used it at work and it works pretty well, escpecially the test reports are very comprehensive and easy to examine.